# Django can't find jade template

Tags: django, pug, pyjade

I've followed the install guide on [pyjade website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjade) and rewritten all my templates in my Django project. However, Django doesn't seem to find templates when I use the extends tag in templates.

```
extends 'base.jade'
```

When I try to extend another template I get this error.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
base.jade

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader pyjade.ext.django.loader.Loader:
```

From my settings.py I have

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
     ('pyjade.ext.django.Loader',(
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'pyjade',
)
```

Is there any known bugs with using pyjade together with Django==1.5.4? The project worked fine using ordinary html templates, I have not changed anything about the folder structure.

EDIT: Added settings and more information.

Comment: Yes, I have. I have two projects using pyjade at the moment. One with Django==1.6.3 and one with Django==1.5.4. The 1.6.3 project works properly and I have the (from what I can see) exact same settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

Didn't really have anything to do with Django not finding the template. It was just errors with poor conversion from HTML to Jade, leaving misspells and templatetags that wasn't closed. Although Pyjade is really nice with Django, it has some drawbacks when it comes errors in templates. It just says line 0 and nothing about where the error is located.

If you have the same problem, a tip would be to check your syntax one more time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @oyvindym, I will try to improve syntax error handling for the next version of pyjade :)